# Why does this gs command fail on --filename.pdf?

Tags: pdf

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. Code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2783/9815)

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newfile.pdf badfile.pdf
```

Outputs:

> Usage: gs ... -- file.ps arg1 ... argn

The expected output: a new .pdf file.

2nd version

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newfile.ps badfile.pdf
```

Same output as above.

[Larsks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280850/16920). I get GPL Ghostscript editor by running `gs`. Command `type -a gs` gives `gs is /usr/bin/gs`. Command `dpkg-query -s ghostscript | grep Version` gives `Version: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2`. So `gs` is ghostscript in my system.

---

Why does the `gs` command fail?

Comment: Is gs complaining because you're passing it a .pdf file instead of a .ps file?

Comment: That doesn't look like a "normal" GPL Ghostscript usage message - do you have some other `gs` installed (Aladin / AFPL maybe?)

Comment: based only on flimsy [archive](http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/1.0-RELEASE/ports/ghostscript/gs/gs.c) evidence, does 'gs' want to see an actual '--' before 'badfile.pdf'?

Comment: `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newfile.pdf -- badfile.pdf` for the first (pdf) example

Comment: From looking at the code, the error message is due to giving gs a `--` argument, i.e. something that looks like a long option without an actual option name. Is `gs` an alias, function, or wrapper script? Is `badfile.pdf` the actual argument, or is there a `--` in its name?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You are completely right! The input file had a name `plaa----plaa.pdf` and some had `---plaa---plaa.pdf`. Please, make your comment an answer so I accept it. How can one include such file names easily?

Comment: @Masi so the issue would have been **much** easier to identify if you had not obfuscated the actual filenames

Comment: @steeldriver True! I am sorry for simplifying too much. My mistake. Not doing so next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gs is complaining about file arguments such as `---plaa---plaa.pdf` because they look like [long options](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html) but aren't.

Workaround: precede the filename argument with a [`--` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) to signal that there are no more options, or use a pathname such as `./---plaa---plaa.pdf`.

Comment: Sure, if you have a case where `gs` doesn't work properly when given pathnames as arguments, please post a question about it, giving an example.

Comment: I extended the case here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280982/16920

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you're not actually running `ghostscript`.  On ubuntu 16.04:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

With ghostscript 9.18:

```
# dpkg-query -s ghostscript | grep Version
Version: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2
```

If I run your example command, I get a standard ghostscript error
message, which looks like this:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (badfile.pdf)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1196/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I suspect that there is something else named `gs` in your `$PATH`.
Some things to check:

- If you just run `gs` by itself, do you find yourself at the `GS>` prompt?

  ```
  # gs
  GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
  Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
  This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
  GS>
  ```
- Does `type -a gs` show `gs is /usr/bin/gs` or something else?
- Does explicitly running `/usr/bin/gs` instead of just `gs` result in
  different behavior?

Comment: I get GPL Ghostscript editor by running `gs`. Command `type -a gs` gives `gs is /usr/bin/gs`. Your other command `Version: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2`. So I think am running ghostscript. What is your output of the command in the body?