# Why does this script not accept two arguments?

Tags: shell-script

Code

```
#!/bin/sh
# http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20886/13173
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280830/16920
# $Id: pdf2eps,v 0.01 2005/10/28 00:55:46 Herbert Voss Exp $
# Convert PDF to encapsulated PostScript.
# usage:
# pdf2eps <page number> <pdf file without ext>

[ $# -lt 2 ] || echo "At least 2 arguments are needed" && exit 1

pdfcrop "$2.pdf"
pdftops -f "$1" -l "$1" -eps "$2-crop.pdf"
rm  "$2-crop.pdf"
mv  "$2-crop.eps" "$2.eps"
```

Run it as

```
pdf2eps 1 ./01-02-2002-01-02-03.pdf
```

Output

> At least 2 arguments are needed

and no output file.

---

Why you cannot run here the command on 01-02.pdf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[ $# -lt 2 ] || echo "At least 2 arguments are needed" && exit 1
```

checks whether the number of arguments is strictly less than 2, and if it's **not**, outputs "At least 2 arguments are needed". You need to replace the `||` with `&&`:

```
[ $# -lt 2 ] && echo "At least 2 arguments are needed" && exit 1
```

I think the example you linked to in [Safe way to install .sh script in /usr/local/bin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280828/safe-way-to-install-sh-script-in-usr-local-bin/280830#280830) is actually easier to understand (and `-ne` is better suited since having more than 2 arguments is probably an error):

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Exactly 2 filenames are needed"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note too that you're not supposed to specify the extension, so you should run the command as

```
pdf2eps 1 ./01-02-2002-01-02-03
```

Comment: My bad. The OP took the `[ $# -lt 2 ] || echo` from [a comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280828/safe-way-to-install-sh-script-in-usr-local-bin/280830?noredirect=1#comment488380_280830) of mine, and I had mistakenly used `||` instead of `&&`. I've now edited the comment as well to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @terdon that's when it's handy to be a moderator ;-).